# Do factory class methods break the Liskov substitution principle?

Tags: python, factory, class-method, liskov-substitution-principle

I was wondering if factory *class* methods break the [Liskov substitution principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle).

For instance in the following Python code, does the `Response.from_request` factory class method break it?

```
import abc


class BaseResponse(abc.ABC):

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def get_headers(self):
        raise NotImplementedError

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def get_body(self):
        raise NotImplementedError


class Response(BaseResponse):

    def __init__(self, headers, body):
        self.__headers = headers
        self.__body = body

    def get_headers(self):
        return self.__headers

    def get_body(self):
        return self.__body

    @classmethod
    def from_request(cls, request, payload):
        headers = request.get_headers()
        headers["meta_data"] = payload["meta_data"]
        body = payload["data"]
        return cls(headers, body)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The substitution principle says that you need to be able to substitute an object with another object of a compatible type (i.e. a subtype), and it must still behave the same. You need to see this from the perspective of a function that type hints for a specific object:

```
def func(foo: BaseResponse):
    ...
```

This function expects an argument that behaves like `BaseResponse`. What does that behave like?

- `get_headers()`
- `get_body()`

These are the only two methods of `BaseResponse`. As long as the object you pass to `func` has these two characteristics, it passes the [duck test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing) of `BaseResponse`. If it further implements any additional methods, that's of no concern.

So, no, class methods don't break the LSP.